# Simulate click on all radio buttons and loop continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Scenario**

I currently have 3 radio buttons that I want to be clicked every 2 seconds. This would keep cycling through over and over until I hit the "Stop" button.

**HTML**

```
<div id="gen">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" />

    <div id="genBtn">
        <button type="button" id="stopBtn">Stop</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every 2 seconds, click each radio button */
    var rollDemRadios = setInterval(function() {
        $('input[name="radios"]').each(function() {
            // You can only see the last one clicked after about 3 seconds
            $(this).click();
        });
    }, 2000);

    /* Stops the radio buttons from rolling */
    $('#stopBtn').click(function() {
        clearInterval(rollDemRadios);
    });
});
```

**Visual Representation**

```
•(click) • •

• •(click) • // after 2 seconds

• • •(click) // another 2 seconds, then click the first one again

[Stop]
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/3xeyf/5/

**Issues**

Why can I only see the last radio button being clicked instead of "each radio button every 2 seconds"?

Also, how do I continuously loop through all 3 radio buttons (after last radio button is clicked, start over to the 1st one)?

**Attempts**

- Enclosed `$(this).click()` with a `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` to make clicking visible to the user's eye.
- Added a `while(true)` inside the `setInterval()` to loop continuously. Not smart, but was worth a try!

Comment: Please add your code in the question as well. If the jsfiddle URL goes down, no one has an idea what your code is.

Comment: @Flater Okay, will do!

Comment: Why? Because ever 2 seconds, you loop through all the 3 radio buttons, and you get to see only the end result, which is the last one being clicked.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses! I will try each answer and give a +1 for working code (if only I can give +0.5 for effort). I'll find which answer is the simplest and most efficient to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in how your code is set up. To explain:

```
var rollDemRadios = setInterval(function() {
    $('input[name="radios"]').each(function() {
        $(this).click();
    });
}, 2000);
```

Let's take away the middle bit, just to simplify things.

```
var rollDemRadios = setInterval(function() {
    DoYourWork();
}, 2000);
```

So, what happens in this snippet? Much like you would expect, every 2 seconds, the browser will run the `DoYourWork()` method. Suppose that it shows you an alert box. That means you will be presented with an alert box every 2 seconds.

But you weren't displaying an alert box. What you are doing is this:

```
    $('input[name="radios"]').each(function() {
        $(this).click();
    });
```

What does this do? For each button found, it clicks it. Very simply put:

```
    firstRadioButton.click();
    secondRadioButton.click();
    thirdRadioButton.click();
```

Let's call this action "Click three buttons sequentially". I'll use this name later on.

Will the code wait between those three click events? No. Why not? You didn't ask it to. You only asked it to wait after having clicked all three buttons.

This is basically what happens:

- **First interval**
- "Click three buttons sequentially". Notice that there is no time set between the three clicks. Those buttons will be clicked as fast as your browser can do it.
- *waiting for two seconds...*
- **Second interval** (two seconds after the first one)
- "Click three buttons sequentially". Notice that there is no time set between the three clicks. Those buttons will be clicked as fast as your browser can do it.
- and so on...

You cannot perceive the three buttons being clicked, because the browser is much faster than your eyes. What you need to do is tell the browser to wait **after clicking each button**. In your current example, you are telling it to **wait after clicking all buttons**. That's the root cause of your issue.

This should space the clicks evenly, waiting 2 seconds per click rather than per batch of clicks:

```
var radiobuttons = $('input[name="radios"]');
var i = 0;

var rollDemRadios = setInterval(function() {
    var currentbutton = radiobuttons[i];

    currentbutton.click();

    i = (i + 1) % radiobuttons.length; //0, then 1, then 2, then 0, then 1, then 2, then 0, ...

}, 2000);
```

Comment: Simple solution as well. Awesome.

Comment: No problem :) I was hoping an explanation would be of more use than a straight up code fix. Also, while everyone here is correct, I find it peculiar that people have stopped using the modulus `%` operator for cyclical int values :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var index = 0,
        $inps = $('input[name="radios"]'),
        len = $inps.length;
    /* Every 2 seconds, click each radio button */
    var rollDemRadios = setInterval(function () {
        $inps.eq(++index % len).click();
    }, 2000);

    $inps.first().click();

    /* Stops the radio buttons from rolling */
    $('#stopBtn').click(function () {
        clearInterval(rollDemRadios);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EfRjE/)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of witch radio is next to be clicked using a variable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current = 0;
    /* Every 2 seconds, click each radio button */
    var rollDemRadios = setInterval(function() {
        $('input[name="radios"]').eq(current).click();
        if (current == 2) { current = 0; } else { current ++; }
   }, 2000);

    /* Stops the radio buttons from rolling */
    $('#stopBtn').click(function() {
        clearInterval(rollDemRadios);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xeyf/6/)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/3xeyf/7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rdoIndex = 0;    
    /* Every 2 seconds, click each radio button */
    var rollDemRadios = setInterval(function() {
        var rdoCount = $('input[name="radios"]').length;
        $('input[name="radios"]:eq(' + rdoIndex%rdoCount + ')').click();
        rdoIndex++;        
    }, 2000);

    /* Stops the radio buttons from rolling */
    $('#stopBtn').click(function() {
        clearInterval(rollDemRadios);
    });
});
```

Here you keep track of the currently clicked radio button and do that index modulus the count of radio buttons in total to continually loop over indexes 0-2.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code in your $document.ready(function(){  });

```
var i=0;    
var rollDemRadios = setInterval(function() {
    if(i===3)
    {
        i=0;
    }
    $('input[name="radios"]:eq('+i+')').click();
    i++;
}, 2000);

/* Stops the radio buttons from rolling */
$('#stopBtn').click(function() {
    clearInterval(rollDemRadios);
});
```

Regards

Comment: Hi @MardeepMehta , thanks this is a really simple, working code. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Just put setTimeout logic

```
var i = 0;
var stop = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
 CheckRadio();
$("#stopBtn").click(function(){
    stop = true;
});

});

function CheckRadio()
{if(!stop){
$($("input[type='radio']")[i]).click();
i +=1;

setTimeout(function(){
     if(i > 2) i =0;
     CheckRadio();

},2000);
}
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anubrij/59NZt/)

Comment: Hi @AnubrijChandra , thanks for the response! Your code works, however I'd prefer not using a global variable for "stop" and instead just use clearInterval().